# asp mvc 2 application merging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i have one site on asp mvc 2 with authentifiation ant etc.
and second site on asp mvc 2, walking near him.
how can i insert second project to first, from vs2010 for example, and debug them in one time, is there any MapRoute to an application, or anything?
i mean both of them have HomeController for example, and simple copiyng files causes invalid situasions. any suggestions apritiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities. Either start two separate instances of Visual Studio, load both sites and run them in debug mode or combine the two projects into a Visual Studio single solution (then you have the possibility to specify multiple start projects in the properties of the solution so that when you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> both web sites will be run in debug mode).